# Android coreLibraryDesugaring not working with Unit Test

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, java-8

In order to use Java 8 features, I added `coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true` and `coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'` to the app's build.gradle file.
But on running Unit test, Null Pointer Exception is thrown.
I am trying to use `putIfAbsent`.
It throws NPE when using it in test too.
Simple code which produces the bug.

```kotlin
@Test
fun testNPE(){
   val map = mutableMapOf<String, Int>()
   val mutableList = map.putIfAbsent("1", 1)!!
}
```

The test passes when I replace `putIfAbsent` with kotlin's extension function `getOrPut`, which makes sense.
App's Default config

```
minSdkVersion 22
targetSdkVersion 30
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong here.